# Ist there Something as a vectorized Backtesting Platform?

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, back-testing, pyalgotrade, backtrader

I got a pandas series of timevalues and 1s for a Trade and 0s for Not to Trade (plus different Takeprofit and stoploss values)
and i am Planing to Backtest it.

However the Last Time I used backtrader I manually had to search the current Time-location in the Pandas series (Which was unbelievably slow).

Is there a libary where i can have something Like a vectorized approach?
(Else so you have any Tipps how i can execute this plan even more efficient?)

Answer (score 0):

[Moonshot](https://github.com/quantrocket-llc/moonshot) is a fast and lightweight vectorized backtester based on pandas. It is one of the backtesters supported in [QuantRocket](https://www.quantrocket.com/), a quantitative research and trading platform.

Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with QuantRocket.